# What is the counter type for Linux's /sys/block/$DEVICE/stat

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive, metrics

What are the counter types for `/sys/block/$DEVICE/stat`?

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/stat
8323741 42381356 464031898 19207478  1940738 49062039 408122282 79935459        0 22315734 99172579
```

Specifically, do they rollover? At what value? The documentation at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt only states they are "decimal values".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are unsigned long integers with a length depending on the platform (32/64 bit). Yes, they can indeed wrap over if the system is very active for very long. You have to consider that when doing any kind of monitoring.

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/iostats.txt